Docker with Conda: GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found, Libstdc++ Issues in Conda/PyTorch Environment**
Question:
I am working on a project using Docker, Conda, and PyTorch. The environment works perfectly on my local macOS, but I encounter the following error when running the Docker container on an Ubuntu-based image:
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproj/../../../libproj.so.25)

Dockerfile:
FROM condaforge/mambaforge:22.11.1-4

ARG PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL

WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y firefox-geckodriver \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy environment.yml
COPY environment.yml .

# Set pip index URL for private repo
ENV PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=${PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL}
ENV PYTHONHASHSEED 0 

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/opt/conda/pkgs conda config --set always_yes yes && \
    mamba env create --file environment.yml && \
    conda clean -afy

COPY . .

environment.yml:
name: etl
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - awswrangler=3.2.1
  - psycopg2=2.9.3
  - beautifulsoup4=4.11.1
  - joblib=1.1.1
  - botocore=1.34.51
  - boto3=1.34.51
  - selenium=4.1.0
  - tqdm=4.64.1
  - sqlalchemy=1.4.39
  - geoalchemy2=0.13.1
  - geopandas=0.12.2
  - rtree=1.0.1
  - scrapy=2.8.0
  - pandas=1.5.2
  - pyarrow=11.0.0
  - openpyxl=3.0.10
  - fiona=1.8.22
  - pyogrio=0.5.0
  - black=23.1.0
  - requests=2.31.0
  - dateparser=1.1.8
  - pip
  - pytorch
  - torchvision
  - torchaudio
  - cpuonly
  - gcc
  - libstdcxx-ng>=12.2.0  # Fix for GLIBCXX version issues
  - zlib>=1.2.11

  

as well it imports a library that has the following requirement.txt
Unidecode==1.3.8
asyncpg==0.29.0
boto3==1.34.132
botocore==1.34.132
gspread==6.1.2
joblib==1.4.2
packaging==24.1
pandas>=2.0.0,<2.1.0
psutil==6.0.0
pyarrow==16.1.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
s3transfer==0.10.2
scikit-learn==1.3.2
scipy>=1.7.0,<1.12.0
six==1.16.0
sqlalchemy==2.0.31
threadpoolctl==3.5.0
tqdm==4.66.4
transformers==4.41.2
tzdata==2024.1

Error Description:
The issue seems to stem from the GLIBCXX version:
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found

I’ve added libstdcxx-ng>=12.2.0 to the Conda environment file to ensure compatibility with the required version, but I still encounter the error when running the Docker container. On my local machine (macOS), the environment works without issues, but it fails in the Ubuntu-based Docker image.
Debug Attempts:

I’ve confirmed that installing libstdcxx-ng should provide the correct GLIBCXX version, but it seems this isn’t working within the Docker image.
Running the environment setup directly on Ubuntu (without Docker) seems to work fine. The issue is specific to the Docker container.
I’ve tried different versions of gcc and libstdcxx-ng without success.

Question:
How can I resolve this GLIBCXX_3.4.29 error in my Docker environment? Is there a better way to manage these dependencies within Conda and Docker?
Things I have considered:

Manually installing the required libstdc++ version in the Docker image.
Using a different base image that may already have the correct GLIBCXX version.
Ensuring compatibility between system libraries and Conda dependencies.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Tags:
docker, conda, pytorch, ubuntu, libstdc++, python-3.8

Feel free to edit and adjust the post as needed before submitting to Stack Overflow.
